# C# adding controls in site master wont reference in asp:loginView

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a site master that I'm adding a few controls too one being a label that updates programmatically. I'm not sure why in the second example I cant reference the object, if maybe my understanding of how the scope works in the site master is wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

This "ClubName" label works as intended

```
 <div class="main">
     <asp:Label ID="ClubName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Although this one doesnt (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    <asp:Label ID="ClubName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
 </asp:LoginView>
```

My code behind code is simply

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameClub.Text = "hello";
    }
```

and the exception error:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label ClubName= HeadLoginView.FindControl("ClubName") as Label;
if(ClubName != null)
     ClubName.Text =   "hello";
```

your aspx label ID is `ClubName` but in your code you access it as `NameClub`. Anyway you can't access controls inside LoginView directly. Use `FindControl` method and get the control as above.

You better Read [**How to: Access Server Controls by ID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Damith, sorry bad example I had to cut back the source for the example and made an error with the NameClub. Is that the case for all asp controls to find children via the FindControl method?

Comment: Not all, if controls inside another container ( here LoginView) you can't access it directly by ID

Answer (score 2):

This already got an answer but just adding one more info which is important to understand of LoginView.

```
The `LoginView` control, when being added onto a page, at a certain time,
only one Template (anonymous or loggedIn ) is applied on the Control
instance, so at that time, we can only retrieve the reference of those
controls in the currently active template( This means we  can't access 
controls in the non-active template).
```

So it always good to determine whether the user has been
authenticated or not and then use the `LoginView.FindControl( stringId)`
to retrieve the control reference. Else we will again see error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`